# Calculating distance on hexagonal grid

Tags: math, graph

I am trying to determine the number of steps that I need to take (heuristic cost in my implementation) to get from one node to another on a hexagonal grid. The current method that I use works for conventional matrixes, but it produces false results for my hexagonal grid.

My current method:

```
private void calculateHeuristicCost(Node node, Node endNode) {
        if(node != null) {
            node.setHeuristicCost(Math.abs(node.getX() - endNode.getX()) + Math.abs(node.getY() - endNode.getY()));
        }
    }
```

Expected:

```
Distance from 'T': 
  [  5][  4][  4][  4][  4]
[  5][  4][  3][  3][  3]
  [  4][  3][  2][  2][  2]
[  4][  3][  2][  1][  1]
  [  3][  2][  1][  T][  1]
```

Actual:

```
Distance from 'T': 
  [  7][  6][  5][  4][  5]
[  6][  5][  4][  3][  4]
  [  5][  4][  3][  2][  3]
[  4][  3][  2][  1][  2]
  [  3][  2][  1][  T][  1]
```

Could you please help me find the correct formula to find the distance between 2 nodes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#distances